Insert data from a data table to Sql
i have been trying to insert data from Excel file > Datatable > Dataset > into Sql table ( dbo.fingerprintslogs ) in database ( fingerprint reader )
i successfully inserted the data to the datatables and the data set .
so now i have been trying to set the insert command in data adapter .
My data table looks like the following :



Employee   ID
Date
Weekday
First Check In
Last Check Out




10
2024-04-15
Monday

15:04


10
2024-04-16
Tuesday
08:46
14:41


10
2024-04-17
Wednesday
08:34



10
2024-04-18
Thursday
07:50
15:18


10
2024-04-20
Saturday
09:00
15:10


10
2024-04-21
Sunday
08:16
15:53


10
2024-04-22
Monday
08:41
15:22


10
2024-04-25
Thursday
08:05



10
2024-04-27
Saturday
08:10



10
2024-04-28
Sunday
07:27



10
2024-04-29
Monday
07:57
16:04


10
2024-04-30
Tuesday
07:40
15:32


101
2024-04-02
Tuesday
08:55
10:54



i used this code in order to loop through all rows in a dataset.table(0) to use the sqlcommand :
   Public conn As New SqlConnection("Server= DESKTOP-C1JI0OA\SQLEXPRESS; TrustServerCertificate=True; Encrypt=true; TrustServerCertificate=true; Trusted_Connection=True; Database = Fingerprint reader;")
   Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
   Dim ds As New DataSet
   Dim query1 As String
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query1, conn)
        ds.Tables.Add(dt1)
        ds.Tables(0).TableName = "Table"
        da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "dbo.fingerprintslogs")
        conn.Open()
        For Each DataTable As DataTable In ds.Tables
            For Each dtrow In DataTable.Rows
                Dim EmployeeID As String = dtrow(0)
                Dim Date1 As String = dtrow(1)
                Dim WeekDay As String = dtrow(2)
                Dim Firstcheckin As String = dtrow(3)
                Dim Lastcheckout As String = dtrow(4)
                query1 = "INSERT INTO fingerprintslogs Values('" & EmployeeID & "','" & Date1 & "','" & WeekDay & "','" & Firstcheckin & "','" & Lastcheckout & "')"
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emloyee ID", SqlDbType.Int)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", SqlDbType.Date)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WeekDay", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First check in", SqlDbType.Time)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last check out", SqlDbType.Time)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                da.InsertCommand = cmd
                da.Update(ds.Tables(0))
            Next
        Next
        conn.Close()

I get error:

ExecuteNonQuery CommandText property has not been properly initialized

and at this point i'm not sure even if the way i'm using is correct  x)

There's an (unnecessary) opening ( before VALUES that isn't closed.

You parametrised the parameters but still inject them; why?

your query1  is only defined after SqlCommand(query1, conn)

@Squirrel  Dim query1 As String i did before the sql command

@Filburt i adjusted ty

@ThomA emm , i though that i had always to set the parameters of the command ?

You have '...Values('" & EmployeeID & "'...' You are injecting the value of EmployeeID. The parameters you define end up not actually being using in the SQL.

@ThomA  wont the parameters change with the command.parameter , since it is actually used after the querry ? , if no any suggestions .?

A quick search gave me: How do I create a parameterized SQL query? Why Should I?

query1 is defined, but NOT initialized before your instantiation of SqlCommand so you pass an empty string which results in the error you quoted. The SqlCommand object will not be notified of theString you passed to it being changed. Make sure you initialize your string, like:
Dim query1 As String = "INSERT INTO fingerprintslogs (Values('@EmployeeID','@Date1','@WeekDay','@Firstcheckin','@Lastcheckout')"
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query1, conn)

note that I added query parameters to your query instead of hard-coding your variables which is unsafe.
It also looks strange that you loop your datatables and each row of each datatable, maybe you wanted to loop a specific datatable instead, but I'm not sure about this.
Fix the parameter names you pass (I have removed the spaces from them):
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmloyeeID", EmployeeID)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date1", Date1)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WeekDay", WeekDay)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstcheckin", Firstcheckin)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastcheckout", Lastcheckout)

And make sure your white-spaces are correct, it does not make sense to have cmd declaration being tabulated to the right in comparison with the declaration of query1 above it.
EDIT
As Andrew Morton pointed out in the comment-section, AddWithValue may cause performance issues, so it is recommended to use something like this instead:
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmloyeeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = EmployeeID
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date1", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Date1
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@WeekDay", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = WeekDay
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Firstcheckin", SqlDbType.Time).Value = Firstcheckin
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Lastcheckout", SqlDbType.Time).Value = Lastcheckout

so that the type will not have to be inferred.

this is great , it works .
great advices as well . thank you .
not sure if this is related but now in the db i'm having a one specific row that's multiplied way too many times ( like 1000 times ), even though all the other 1600+ rows are correctly inserted .
( this does not happen when in the datagridview of the ds.tables(0)
this happened when i hardcoded the parameters
but when used query parameter i get error says " conversion failed when converting the varchar value '@EmployeeID' to data type int .
even though i double checked the ds/dt and there were all int data in the column

the row where the first problem happens was the first row in the file that is shown in the question .

@RodwanAlburie the parameter issue is due to a typo on my part. Let me edit my answer

@RodwanAlburie fixed the adding of the parameters.

@RodwanAlburie as about the duplicated row, I advise you to ask a separate question where you could detail which row it is (I suppose the last row you wanted) and add further context, because the current question is focused on executing the query, not on how and when it is scheduled to be executed. If/when you are ready with the next question (please add there lots of details), then you can let me know about it here in the comment section. If this answer solved your issue of not being able to run the SQL command, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

So why do we remove the the sqldbtype parameters ? won't this affect the db in anyway? , and as i understood this edit means that i should rewrite the hard coded vraiables ? , cuz the parameter issue only happens when i use the query parameters not the hard coded ones

@RodwanAlburie you still need to pass those parameters, not the types (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=netframework-4.8.1). The problem with hard-coding them into the SQL text like you previously did is that it is highly unsafe due to SQL injection (see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp), because if you have a command like delete from users where username like '%somevaluehere%', then a hacker may inject an empty string into somevaluehere and remove all users...

@RodwanAlburie similarly updates, inserts, selects can be hacked via SQL injection if the parameters are hard-coded into the query text. Instead, there is a general-purpose solution against SQL injection in the form of parameterized queries, that is, you put placeholders into the query, like @EmployeeID and later on you specify what value you've meant @EmployeeID to be. So the functionalities under the hood will take the value you passed to AddWithValue as the second parameter, knowing that it's supposed to be a parameter and will escape it, that is,

@RodwanAlburie if you search of O'Brian, for example, then the apostrophe inside your search parameter, between O and Brian will not be understood as the end of the string by the tool which is supposed to execute your query against the database.

Thanks for your time and explanation , you surely helped me Alot with this , i will let you know when i post about the new problem

@RodwanAlburie sure thing, happy to help. I'm looking forward for the other question.

@LajosArpad Just so you know: AddWithValue is Evil, AddWithValue is evil!, and Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?.

@AndrewMorton thanks for pointing that out! I have edited my answer accordingly.

You absolutely should NOT be creating a new command object on every iteration of the loop. What you should be doing is creating one command and adding the parameters to it before the loop, then setting the Value of each parameter on each iteration of the loop.

@jmcilhinney thanks for pointing it out. Edited my answer accordingly.

@LajosArpad  Here is the question :)) would appreciate of you check this .
(https://stackoverflow.com/q/79171286/28101561.com)

@LajosArpad a 3rd update as well xD Saving Date / DateTime type values in Data Tables

@RodwanAlburie please check the answer I have written for the first question and let me know if it works for you

If you have a DataTable, you should not be looping over it and inserting the data one row at a time. You should be using a data adapter to save to whole lot in one go, e.g.
Using command As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table1 (Column1, Column2) VALUES (@Column1, @Column2)",
                                connection),
      adapter As New SqlDataAdapter With {.InsertCommand = command}
    With command.Parameters
        .Add("@Column1", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Column1")
        .Add("@Column2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Column2")
    End With

    adapter.Update(table)
End Using


i tried to test this just now , i copied and adjusted this and it returns an error " conversion from string "Date" to type integer is not valid , any idea ?

Columns data type in table and parameters data type of that field should be same.

@RodwanAlburie, you obviously did it wrong but, as I can't see what you did, I can't see what's wrong with it. The only place you should have "Date" is in the name of your second column, so how you managed to make that the value for a different column is anyone's guess. If you want to do it this way, which you should, then I suggest that you create a new question with a link back to this one and the code you used to try to implement what I suggested. We can then see what you did and what you did wrong.
