Converting from string to type date is not valid
I'm trying to import data from an excel file > Data table > Data set > Db data table
Since I don't really understand where the problem actually started so that's a pretty long code.
The error occurs on this line of code:
Dim Date1 As DateTime = dtrow(1)

Full code:
 Dim dt1 As New DataTable
 Dim dt2 As New DataTable

 Dim firstrow As Boolean = True

 For Each row As IXLRow In ws2.Rows.Skip(1)

      If firstrow Then
          For Each cell As IXLCell In row.Cells
              dt1.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString)
          Next
          firstrow = False
      End If
      Exit For
  Next

  For Each row As IXLRow In ws2.Rows.Skip(2)
      dt1.Rows.Add()
      Dim i As Integer = 0
      For Each cell As IXLCell In row.Cells()
          dt1.Rows(dt1.Rows.Count - 1)(i) = cell.Value.ToString()
          i += 1
      Next
  Next

  'importing data from dt1 into db'

  ds.Tables.Add(dt1)
  da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "dbo.fingerprintslogs")
  ds.Tables(0).TableName = "Table"

  conn.Open()

  Dim query = " Delete From Fingerprintlogs"
  Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, conn)
  da.DeleteCommand = cmd
  da.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

  DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
  For Each dtrow As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows

      Dim EmployeeID As Integer = dtrow(0)
      Dim Date1 As DateTime = dtrow(1)
      Dim WeekDay = dtrow(2)
      Dim Firstcheckin As DateTime = dtrow(3)
      Dim Lastcheckout As DateTime = dtrow(4)
      Dim query1 = "INSERT INTO fingerprintslogs Values('" & EmployeeID & "','" & Date1 & "','" & WeekDay & "','" & Firstcheckin & "','" & Lastcheckout & "')"
      Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand(query1, conn)
      cmd1.Parameters.Add("@EmloyeeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = EmployeeID
      cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Date1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Date1
      cmd1.Parameters.Add("@WeekDay", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = WeekDay
      cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Firstcheckin", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Firstcheckin
      cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Lastcheckout", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Lastcheckout
      cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
      da.InsertCommand = cmd1
      da.Update(ds.Tables(0))
  Next
  conn.Close()

The error is

Conversion from string "2024-04-15" to type 'Date' is not valid

Here is a sample of the data originally from the Excel file:



First In Last Out








Employee   ID
Date
Weekday
First Check In
Last Check Out


10
2024-04-15
Monday

15:04


10
2024-04-16
Tuesday
08:46
14:41


10
2024-04-17
Wednesday
08:34





I made sure all the column was set to date in the Excel file

I tried to remove the .ToString when filling the data table here:
 For Each cell As IXLCell In row.Cells()
         dt1.Rows(dt1.Rows.Count - 1)(i) = cell.Value.ToString()
         i += 1
  Next


I made sure the column is set to Date in the data base & when Date1 variable was Date

Then I tried changing everything to Date Time


But the error still appears.
Update :
i used this code to insert the the data set into db :
 Using command As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Fingerprintlogs (EmployeeID, Date, WeekDay, FirstCheckIn,LastCheckOut ) VALUES (@EmployeeID, @Date, @WeekDay, @FirstCheckIn, @LastCheckOut)", conn), adapter As New SqlDataAdapter With {.InsertCommand = command}
     With command.Parameters
         .Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "EmployeeID")
         .Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime, 0, "Date")
         .Add("@WeekDay", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "WeekDay")
         .Add("@FirstCheckIn", SqlDbType.DateTime, 0, "FirstCheckIn")
         .Add("@LastCheckOut", SqlDbType.DateTime, 0, "LastCheckOut ")
     End With
     adapter.Update(ds.Tables(0))
 End Using

& ended up with the same error :
Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime, FormatException: String '2024-04-15' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
in this case the error occurs on this line of code :
adapter.Update(ds.Tables(0))


Side note: your query is open to SQL Injection. You specify parameters, but you aren't using those parameters in your query string-- you're concatenating variables into the query string, which is not secure.

Noted , thank you @devlincarnate

For some reason the OP has ignored that advice multiple times, @devlincarnate . I suspect at this point it's an intentional security flaw. That the error is because of the flaw makes their choice even more confusing.

@ThomA sorry for misunderstanding , the thing is this is supposed to be a personal offline application ( for my own use )  , this is the reason i did not want to take security into account , plus i had ended up with the same exact error using the method mentioned by "jmcilhinney" in the former question :(

Personal or not, parametrisation should always be used.

Understood , You may check the update in this question , i had the same error using the query parameters . @ThomA

"Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime, FormatException" - is a different error. It is not the same as  "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"  previously it was a SQL Server error now it is a VB.NET error. You need to debug what the parameter value is that is being set.

well i just followed this suggestion of not looping over the the table rows and inserting the whole thing at one go and using query parameters , but seems like i missed something up @MartinSmith

If you want to insert Date values into the database then you need to start with Date values in the DataTable you're saving from. Stop putting Strings in there in the first place. Stop doing this dt1.Rows(dt1.Rows.Count - 1)(i) = cell.Value.ToString(). Save the actual data as the actual type it represents and stop expecting the system to do all that for you.

@jmcilhinney Hello , i actually found out that the error originated on this line yesternight while debugging the Datatypes of the columns .  you can check the new question Saving Date / DateTime type values in Data Tables

I don't know the root of the problem with VB not auto recognizing it's a date, but this sample should help you.
 Dim Date1 As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dtrow(1).ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd", 
        System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)


Using this shows  error : 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'      error line :  ' cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()'

Very strange, you sure that dtrow(1) represents exactly string '2024-04-15' when stepping on it from debug? See this .NET article about string conversion.

@RodwanAlburie  "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" is an error from SQL Server not VB.NET - as you are just concatenating it into the string and passing it as a string. You've declared parameters and you should use them. Your SQL should be something like INSERT INTO fingerprintslogs (EmloyeeID,Date1,WeekDay,Firstcheckin,Lastcheckout)Values(@EmloyeeID,@Date1,@WeekDay,@Firstcheckin,@Lastcheckout)

Opsie ! , the former error in my comment was due to a typo in query1 and made it referring to a different data table ,, well now it shows this error ((" The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated"))

i will try using the query parameters and see if this is fixed , @MartinSmith

If you use the query parameters you only have to deal with the conversion to date in VB.NET not in two places. If you still see "out of range" kind of errors that would indicate the date you are passing is probably something like 0001-01-01 so you need to investigate that

i just did , you may check the update in this question :( @MartinSmith

You are attempting to specify the names of your parameters as the values you want to insert, instead of their values in your code:
 Using command As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Fingerprintlogs (EmployeeID, Date, WeekDay, FirstCheckIn,LastCheckOut ) VALUES (@EmployeeID, @Date, @WeekDay, @FirstCheckIn, @LastCheckOut)", conn), adapter As New SqlDataAdapter With {.InsertCommand = command}
     With command.Parameters
         .Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "EmployeeID")
         .Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime, 0, "Date")
         .Add("@WeekDay", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "WeekDay")
         .Add("@FirstCheckIn", SqlDbType.DateTime, 0, "FirstCheckIn")
         .Add("@LastCheckOut", SqlDbType.DateTime, 0, "LastCheckOut ")
     End With
     adapter.Update(ds.Tables(0))
 End Using

The problem is that you did not pass the actual values. You are using this override of Add and you intend to specify some source columns, but the documentation clearly states that this fourth parameter stands for

The name of the source column (SourceColumn) if this SqlParameter is used in a call to Update.

You are doing an Insert, not an Update, so you have no source-columns, no earlier values of the row you are just creating. Instead you need to pass your variables properly, like:
 Using command As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Fingerprintlogs (EmployeeID, Date, WeekDay, FirstCheckIn,LastCheckOut ) VALUES (@EmployeeID, @Date, @WeekDay, @FirstCheckIn, @LastCheckOut)", conn), adapter As New SqlDataAdapter With {.InsertCommand = command}
     With command.Parameters
         .Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.Int, 0)
         .Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime, 0)
         .Add("@WeekDay", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
         .Add("@FirstCheckIn", SqlDbType.DateTime, 0)
         .Add("@LastCheckOut", SqlDbType.DateTime, 0)
     End With
     command.Parameters("@EmployeeID").Value = EmployeeID
     command.Parameters("@Date").Value = Date1
     command.Parameters("@WeekDay").Value = WeekDay
     command.Parameters("@FirstCheckIn").Value = Firstcheckin
     command.Parameters("@LastCheckOut").Value = Lastcheckout
     adapter.Update(ds.Tables(0))
 End Using

Your line of
Dim Date1 As DateTime = dtrow(1)

throws the exception you received because the implicit conversion failed. You can try
Dim Date1 As DateTime = CDate(dtrow(1))

that explicitly tries to convert the type. Or, you can try doing an exact parse using your data format:
Dim Date1 As DateTime = Date.ParseExact(dtrow(1), "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)


Doesn't the error ("Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime, FormatException: String '2024-04-15' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.") indicates that the value (" 2024-04-15') was successfully passed into add ?

plus , i removed the hard-coded variables , i had tried the CDate & Parse and it was still showing the same kind of data type error .
but you may check this question : Saving Date / DateTime type values in Data Tables  since i suspected that the Datatype error was originally generated because of the data table columns types .

@RodwanAlburie no, not recognizing '2024-04-15' as a valid DateTime means it fails to pass this string to Date1 Dim Date1 As DateTime = dtrow(1)

So , using this , is there any way i can pass cell values into the command.parameter without looping into the rows one at the time and without using a hard-coded variables ? , this was a suggestion i got before here

@RodwanAlburie you can have your values as String and convert them into date when you are inserting them.
